# Add an assessment to your Developer Story

Tags: discussion, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

### TL;DR

- We’ve added a new item type called ‘Assessments’ to Developer Story.
- You can take a free skill assessment on Pluralsight and add your Pluralsight Skill IQ to your Developer Story.

### WHY

Developer Story was built to give you a way to show off what you know and what you've built. Incorporating things like open source projects, top questions, and articles or blog posts were designed to help expand your story beyond typical education and work experience.

But how do you show language proficiency? While earned reputation can be a good indicator of proficiency, one should be hesitant to draw direct parallels between their reputation and overall language proficiency. Proficiency is just one variable in building reputation.

And what about the many developers who have the skills but haven’t been able to publicly demonstrate them for various reasons? Perhaps the company they work for has proprietary software, making it hard to ask questions or share projects publicly; perhaps they’ve been stuck [working without](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344282/if-youre-on-a-classified-network-how-are-you-reading-this) ready access to [the Internet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352167/10-hours-of-netflix-vs-the-size-of-stack-overflow/352168#352168). Some folks may simply feel intimidated to jump in the deep end and ask or answer questions. We’ve recognized this issue for a long time and adding new ways to enable people to show off their skills is important to us.

This is why are excited to partner with Pluralsight and their Pluralsight IQ product. Pluralsight's goal to help developers learn and grow in their development knowledge is one that we, at Stack Overflow, enthusiastically support and share. And their new product, Pluralsight IQ, allows each developer to measure their skill level in about 5 minutes. To better understand the technology that powers Pluralsight IQ, check out their [blog post](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/news/pluralsight-iq-assessments) about measuring and building tech skills.

### HOW IT WORKS

Starting today, you'll see a new "Assessments" item on the Developer Story. When you click this link, an instructional dialogue will open along with a link. This link will take you to Pluralsight's website, where you will have to log in or create a free account.

[image: Add new item]

Once logged in, select an assessment to take or one you've already completed. Then on your Skill IQ results page, click the Stack Overflow icon to share your Skill IQ on your Developer Story. Here is what a Skill IQ will look like on your timeline:

[image: timeline item]

In addition to adding your Skill IQ to your timeline, we'll also add an abbreviated version to the header portion of your Developer Story.

[image: profile]

Of course you have the ability to remove any Skill IQ from  your Developer Story whenever you want.

[Take an assessment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/edit/current/new-item?itemType=7#item-add), add it to your story, and let us know what you think! If you find a bug, please report them either by posting them as an answer to this question or by posting questions with the tags [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [developer-story](/questions/tagged/developer-story) [pluralsight-iq](/questions/tagged/pluralsight-iq).

Comment: the assessment cannot be viewed in the traditional view?

Comment: @Hadi nope, we're only including it in the developer story view initially :)

Comment: This seems cool! Sadly, I don't know about anything really useful, just PHP. ;)

Comment: Can assessments be retaken? That is, if I score medium now, and then go learn something, am I stuck with my old score forever or can I test again?

Comment: @RobertColumbia You can “retake” an assessment once more for free. After that, you can remeasure, which will track your progress within that skill. You can unlock a remeasurement after watching 60% of the content of the corresponding path level (course content on Pluralsight).

Comment: I just realized after connecting the Pluralsight account, my account was automatically subscribed to the course "[Using Stack Overflow and Other Stack Exchange Sites](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites)". Refer to "Subscription & Billing" page

Comment: What's about Microsoft Certified Professional certification? Would be they supported?

Comment: @SamuelLiew yes, thats a freebie given to users who sign up through the integration.

Comment: @YohDeadfall are you asking if Pluralsight would support Microsoft Certified Professional certification or if Developer Story will support certifications?

Comment: Developer Story, because it's a good sign to employer. I've added my certificates as Certification items and it's okay, but for now they ain't so shiny as Pluralsight IQ. As Matthieu M. said, Pluralsight IQ doesn't show your real skills, but certificates do since you should pass an exam without any help.

Comment: It would be nice if certificates which could be validated via API would be highlighted. I know that it's possible for MCP.

Comment: @YohDeadfall thanks for clarifying. Third party validation would certainly be a nice addition for certifications. There aren't any plans for that right now but we'll keep this in mind!

Comment: I read that as, "add an assembly"...

Comment: I'm wondering where I can see what happened to my technical feedback on one of the questions ... I find nothing in their equivalent of the help-center and I'm somewhat miffed that I can give feedback, but don't get any chance to follow up on it..

Comment: @g3rv4 i think it can be added to the traditional view in the same way that the Stack Exchange reputations are shown

Comment: How do these retakes work exactly? It says there is one for “free”, but is there a way get another one eventually (without paying for a subscription and watching content)? I got distracted when I took my first test and the time ran out for one question, and another question was asked in a really weird way which made me think about it for too long. So I’m thinking of retaking it immediately but I don’t want to lock myself into the result in case I want to retake it again in the future when I feel more confident with it. But paying for a subscription is really not worth that.

Comment: I've taken Pluralsight assessments in the past.  Can I link these past assessments to my Developer Story or do I have to retake them?

Comment: I've just verified myself that linking my SO profile to Pluralsight does add the option on older assessments, but you need to view them on a specific page.

Comment: @poke You can do a retake and then if you want you can do a remeasurement after watching 60% of the class.  You will get a free trial for classes by signing up, so it is a no cost option (and a way to learn some things too)

Comment: @Des i finished Managing Windows Network test but it doesn't has a related technology tag in the Developer Story. Please take a look at the answer i provided

Comment: @g3rv4 did you have any idea about the issue that i mentioned?

Comment: @Hadi the one about the assessment missing the tag? in that case: yes. We've reached out to them so that they update the tags on it.

Comment: @g3rv4 thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @Hadi done, they've added tags to the courses that didn't have them, and I've backfilled all the existent assessments, so all of them should have tags now. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @g3rv4 it is necessary to add status-completed tag to my answer?

Comment: @Hadi absolutely ;)

Comment: @Des Thanks for all of the information. Without the information from your post, it would be difficult for a user to find out how to enable this integration. Honestly speaking, the user journey needs some polishing. (Disclaimer: I'm completely new to Pluralsight. Existing Pluralsight users might have known that the user journey would be similar to the LinkedIn integration.)

Comment: This pluarlsight IQ thing doesn't show up on the developer story being sent to employers in my case. I tried downloading a version of the one sent to the employer and nothing regards the pluralsight IQ where I scored as expert in about 5 different languages showed up on it. If it isn't going to be showing up, what is is doing to my profile?

Answer (score 57):

For anyone who, like me, struggled for fifteen minutes to find the "add to SO" button on Pluralsight IQ's results page, please see the annotation below:

[image: Screenshot of Pluralsight IQ results page, with "add to SO" button circled]

Comment: Because of the squareness of the circle, it took me 15 minutes to find it in your screenshot

Comment: Hope this one will be more obvious

Comment: It's a meta meme @LongRanger -> See [Freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/203553)

Comment: Just noting... you censored the XX% but not the 89th percentile.

Comment: Curious about its format. Can you explain that a bit? Is it all multi-choice questions? You get some debugging questions? Questions on syntax?

Comment: "enter image description here" is an instruction; you are supposed to follow it. Otherwise the visually impaired have no earthly idea what your image shows.

Answer (score 45):

I'm going to put my hands up here and be honest: I cheated. I didn't know the answer to one of the questions, but it had a 20 second timer, and with my relatively fast internet connection I Googled it.

I'm not sure how much of a language proficiency test this will be for some people over it being a 'how good at searching for answers are you' test. But I guess being able to search for answers is a skill, right?

I'm quite tempted to pick one of the tests which I have absolutely no knowledge in, just to see how quickly I can Google against the clock.

---

**Edit:** Okay, I did it. I Googled myself into MySQL Expert level:

[image]

I got two answers wrong because I was too hasty, and the answers were one or two characters different from each other.

Disclaimer: I have a score of 3 in the [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tag from 2013. I'm not a MySQL expert; I'm a fraud.

Comment: And if you'd not done so well, you could have used the free retake and seen about half the questions a second time and not needed The Google. ;)

Comment: But doesn't the fact that you took less than 20 seconds to answer a question show a level of skill too?

Comment: @DavidG: It certainly does, but the questions are WAY too easy to show *expertise*.

Comment: @MatthieuM. And I would hope any recruiter would know the difference between an assessment "expert" and a bona fide expert :)

Comment: @DavidG: Sure. It's not the point though. If anybody with a modicum of google-fu can grab the Expert tag, then it's just noise on the Developer Story.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I actually think that good Google-fu is a desirable skill, just look at 90% of the questions on here that could be answered by people in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @DavidG: Sure. But Google-fu doesn't make one an expert in a technology. Expertise requires experience.

Comment: I got a 230 score with **NO experience** in MySQL (only some experience with SQL and Oracle, about 10 years ago ) and **NO Googling**, just guessing...

Comment: @Adinia hello, fellow expert.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I thought it might just be that MySQL syntax is quite simple and human-readable, but then I got an "almost expert"(187, proficient) in Python as well, and I never read or saw anything before about it.

Comment: I agree - this pluralsight stuff is useless, as it is all googlable

Answer (score 23):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Stop calling me slack!

OK, it's just a spelling mistake...

[image]

Comment: **_Slack_** Overflow - sounds like an appropriate name for a community full of overpaid developers who take any interest in the industry or in what they're doing solely during that period of the month when they're about to get their fat paycheck :)  I'm afraid I've already seen it before... *wink*

Comment: how embarrassing... Should be fixed in a few short minutes.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson If it helps, I did have a good giggle about it! I see it's fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 22):

I tried the C++ assessment for fun, and managed to get 270/300 (and 286/300 on 2nd try). I guess this makes me an expert, and yet...

---

I wasn't too keen on some questions:

- 1 code snippet exhibited Undefined Behavior (out-of-bounds access on a vector), but the question was "what is the last line printed"... in case of UB, no line? Any line? The "right" answer depends on your compiler, compiler options, and possibly the phase of the moon...
- a number of snippets are about the formatting options of streams (I picked seemingly at random, who uses streams for serious formatting?),
- another snippet is about "Good Design", which is somewhat subjective.

Out of 20 questions, I find 4/5 to be questionable.

---

The *other* questions, were mostly about syntax or compiler-detectable errors.

This is pretty uninteresting, really. I expect a Junior Developer with only a couple years C++ under their belt to do as well as I did on those.

I got no question about templates, SFINAE, `constexpr`, `decltype`, move semantics, ... in the first attempt even though those are pretty common in C++11 and beyond and a "Proficient" C++ developer would need to know them.

And I got no question on the C++ memory model, aliasing, placement `new`, and other "system-y" parts of the C++ language which distinguish "Proficient" from "Expert".

---

So, yeah, if I open http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ in parallel of the assessment and I am fast enough in copy/pasting, I can breeze by all questions on "what does this print".

And those are the harder questions.

I don't intend of showing off those scores on my account; they were much too easy to attain. Maybe the Beginner/Proficient levels are well calibrated, I wouldn't know, but the Expert one is much too easy by itself... and much too easy to *game*.

Comment: I had only one question of the "what does this print?" in C#. Definitely agreed that those aren't very good questions. Conversely I had *only one question* dealing with covariance/contravariance.

Comment: I still consider this valuable; I could hire you, throw a language at you that you haven't used very much, and trust that you'd be able to Google / learn your way through it and actually accomplish something. Granted the context there is a lot different than presenting one as an 'expert' when in reality the person is just good at finding answers to stuff, but it's just one bit of signal that the person is capable of answering questions and has at least a reasonable grasp on a given technology. I agree with you, I think I just find more value in it.

Answer (score 18):

## This is neat.

I took the C# and Unity tests.

A couple of the questions felt *really* obscure (eg. "When would you use the platform #define directives?") or something I hadn't come across yet (eg. "What is the purpose of the masking part of an animation clip?" or another one about hot keys that I just plain don't use). But I suppose that is what would distinguish an expert user from a beginning user!

The "one free retake" is very nice. Used it for the C# test (which I did first, as it was presented up front and I had to dig a little to find the Unity one). There were a few questions that I got wrong and went "oh, duh" (e.g. "which alternative expression would give exactly the same string value?" with the answer of `"The code is\r\n3\\48-\"apple\"\\r\\n"`, I'd been squinting at that answer and another, and had trouble seeing the difference between them: double backslashes vs `\r\n`. It had sort of turned into symbolic soup under the time pressure).

Scored in the 230s for both and added both to my developer profile.

## But...

Only *technical problem* I had was that I inadvertently double-clicked at one point and got a question wrong before I'd even read it. Might want to enforce a bit of input delay! The same kind of "prevent clicks" like during the review queues, just to make sure people are actually reading the question. I'm not sure I'd have gotten the question right even if I'd been able to read it, but it was a problem that I didn't get the opportunity.

I'm considering taking some others, but I know I'm significantly less skilled in the other skill paths that are currently available. e.g. I *could* take one of the Photoshop assessments but I actually don't use *Photoshop proper,* so I'm sure there'd be a question where my response would be "Heck if I know, but I know how to do this in GIMP!" and I'm concerned that a lower score displayed on my developer story would actually hurt me more than help.

That is, I don't know if these are going to be viewed as "icing" or "cake." Clearly the intent is for the scoring to be supplementary, but I'm worried that hiring managers are going to boil a profile down into a handful of numbers and say "this guy scored low on some of his skills and displayed them? Skip!" instead of "this guy is an expert in what we need, and is well rounded with a few other skills. Hired!"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on your experience! We'll pass along the bit about double-clicking to the Pluralsight team.  Also, you can absolutely take more assessments without sharing them on your Developer Story. And, if you do share more and change your mind, you can remove them. Employers won't see this yet as we haven't introduced it on the "traditional CV view" but we plan to do that in the future.

Comment: @Des I knew I didn't have to add them to my developer story, it was more a concern with *doing that step* after taking them. But thanks for the reply. :)

Answer (score 15):

[The blog said](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/06/pluralsight-stack-overflow-helping-worlds-developers-learn-new-skills/):

> How You Can Participate
>
> Take an assessment, add it to your Developer Story, and let us know what you think!

OK, here's my feedback. Tell your partner: demanding yet another log-in is a really super annoying thing to do; if you wanna appear clue- and respectful, then treat us well and allow log-in via OpenID.

That's why [you implemented it in the first place](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/27/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/), right?

[image]

Comment: And... they listened to you! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-1-2018?cb=1

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Not sure if I missed a step, but I took the android test and the results are not shown on my storyline. It just shows a generic pluralsight image, and a plain [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) with no score next to it.

[image]

I signed up there via the link from the email. Also had some issues where my account was created automatically, but without a password, making me unable to log in. Fixed via password reset.

Comment: I'm getting this same behaviour and haven't figured anything further out myself

Comment: Same here, although I didn't have any issues creating my account. Scores don't show up on developer story but there is a place for them.

Comment: Same here, and even weirder is that it moves my assessment down the timeline.

Comment: @dcodesmith was the same for me because the assessment took place earlier in time than "currently", and I still had my old job listed as "currently working here"

Comment: Have you managed to fix the score not showing? @TimCastelijns

Comment: we're working on fixing it right now

Comment: Same here. Thank you @g3rv4.

Comment: Sam here. Please fix. Thanks

Comment: confirmed. Also did the android test, seems the issue affects certain tags more than others

Comment: we are working with Pluralsight to resolve the issue and once we have a fix, we will backfill all the assessments that are showing incorrectly. I will update here once that's done.

Comment: This should be temporarily fixed now. We are working with Pluralsight on a permanent fix, and we're going to be backfilling the bogus assessments. If you don't want to wait for the backfill, you can delete the assessments from your dev story and share them again. Also, there's now [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363093/920295) with the bug report. We'll keep that one updated with our progress.

Comment: This has been fixed, and all the assessments have been backfilled. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Yes, it works! Also, now I can see the image under the `Add skill IQ`. Thank you @g3rv4

Answer (score 9):

I quickly tried the JavaScript "assessment" and closed it after 12 or so questions as already 4 or 5 of the questions were of the "aha" variety, such as these gems:

What is the result of: `Math.max()`
 i.e. without passing any arguments, or:

What is the result of:
`new Boolean(new Boolean(false)).valueOf()`

These kinds of tests don't rate your skill or "IQ" in anything, but just check if you've picked up on a bunch of pub-quiz trivia knowledge that is completely irrelevant in the real world.

Answer (score 9):

## 2020 Update

[image: Pluralsight Score]
I tried to add my Pluralsight to my story but there is no Stack**overflow** icon on the site any more.

Is the support for Pluralsight integration stoped?
If yes why is there still the Assessment button to add it?
When no can someone tell me where the new location is of the Stack**overflow** icon / button

Comment: Have the same issue right now... However a few months back there was no problem with it.

Comment: Furthermore if you look at the source code of the page, the "sharing_container" div is there but the content is not visible, obviously a bug.

Comment: Okay, found a workaround, just resize your browser window. Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/5YtNvTd).

Comment: Resizing worked. Just had to figure out first that I had to click on `View details`

Comment: I had the same problem.. Pluralsight has not been a hit for me so far.

Comment: @michalk... that did the trick... had to uncheck `display:none` in `Developer Tools`. Here's the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/cvgJUDZ.png

Answer (score 8):

Given that previously I've only been able to share the PluralSight score on LinkedIn, I must thank you for this, it does look really great:

[image]

Hopefully now my employer sees the benefit of PluralSight...

Answer (score 5):

### Here is the Stack Overflow link

It took me quite a while to find out where the Stack Overflow icon was. I did a quick test to check how it works and could not find the Stack Overflow icon. I spent perhaps 30 minutes on this. Including then making a GIF image :)

I do not think Pluralsight inspires me any confidence. I did not have the feeling that questions were well thought. More of the same multiple choice style over and over. I am not a network administrato, and still I could score a median note.

For those who wonder, here is how you get to the Stack Overflow link if you are not on a mobile device: You will need to resize your browser!

[image: Pluralsight screenshot GIF image]

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I finished **Managing Windows Network** test, and added it successfully to my developer story, But it shows no technology tag, also it doesn't appear with other test results on the top of my story.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Tried twice. Both times, I had to reload the page several times to go on and a few answers timed out in the meanwhile. A very poor experience. Right now it's not worth to try it.

Comment: Adblocker maybe? Worked as expected for me.

Comment: Me too. Even with the best VPNs I've used, the network lag and timeout is rather annoying.

Answer (score -1):

Push the <kbd>F12</kbd> key on the website and search for the `.badgeSharing__25Y-w` keyword:

[image]

Then at the element, search for *display* and instead of this code:

```
display: none;
```

use this:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: Modifying CSS on the fly? What browser? Firefox? What about other browsers?

Comment: I do it on firefox.