# Assessments are not visible in Traditional view of Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

I just added some assessments to [my Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/story/the4kman) and discovered that they are not visible [in Traditional view](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/the4kman):

**Story view**

[image: assessments in Story view]

**Traditional view**

[image: no assessments in Traditional view]

Comment: This was mentioned in a comment on the announcement post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/add-an-assessment-to-your-developer-story#comment553348_362730

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yup, I saw that one right after I asked this question. It still needs a separate thread IMO. Moreover, it seems like a bug, since the two viewing options contain the same data in every other section.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to imply that you shouldn't have asked this question because of that. Just FYI in case you hadn't seen it.

Comment: Is there a reason you have 2 [photoshop] scores? Did you take it twice and feature both?

Comment: @River Nope, those are 2 different courses, namely "Photoshop: Digital Art and Illustration" and "Photoshop: Photo Manipulation".

Comment: @River There's actually *three* different Photoshop courses (the third one is for "Creative Professionals"). And a whopping **five** Maya courses (Core, Modeling, Characters, Environment, and Dynamic Core). But only one for 3D Max (Environment).

Comment: @the4kman thanks for opening a separate thread. I've updated the status on this since we're actively reviewing it.