# Developer story Traditional view needs Skill IQ

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

With the blog post [Pluralsight & Stack Overflow: Helping the World’s Developers Learn New Skills](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/06/pluralsight-stack-overflow-helping-worlds-developers-learn-new-skills/?cb=1)
and this meta post, [Add an assessment to your Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/add-an-assessment-to-your-developer-story)
The SO Developer Story has got a new section for Skill IQ, thanks for that.

However, when I checked traditional view for the Developer story, I still can't see a section for the same.

When will that be added?

Comment: Also when you are making the title for your question, no need to put "Pluralsight IQ" in the title. [It's already in the tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), so putting it in the title is redundant.