# Pluralsight skill iq test added to dev story seems to be displayed wrongly

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

I just took and pass my 1st pulralsight skill iq test and got it added to my dev story where its listed without any details like the score, validation, etc. I tried one more time and the same happened. May this be a bug? Oo

[image]

[image]

Comment: This should be temporarily fixed now. We are working with Pluralsight on a permanent fix, and we're going to be backfilling the bogus assessments. If you don't want to wait for the backfill, you can delete the assessments from your dev story and share them again.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your report. This is fixed now, and all the assessments with this issue have been backfilled.