# Pluralsight IQ credibility and quality/relevance of their tests

Tags: discussion, pluralsight-iq

I did the "MySQL" test and found the questions heavily weighted towards the DBA role (eg obscure questions about log file configuration etc.) rather than the coder role. Since the results of such tests are being associated with *Stack Overflow* accounts, for *coders* (and not [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) accounts, for *DBAs*), I don't believe the results of the MySQL Pluralsight test have much relevance to Stack Overflow user profiles.

I have seen numerous grumblings about Pluralsight, so I suppose I'm more or less putting Pluralsight on trial here, including an open discussion to consider removing all connections with them.

Has anybody vetted Pluralsight?

Do they actually have any credibility in the industry?

Does anybody else think Pluralsight's tests are poor quality or not relevant to members of the Stack Overflow community?

Comment: Related: _"[Pluralsight IQ incorrect questions in test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363251/pluralsight-iq-incorrect-questions-in-test)"_

Comment: The IQ tests are filled with incorrect answers, vague questions, questions that are unrelated to the subject you're doing a test about (Half of the HTML5 test is about JS / canvas, I'd expect more HTML semantics). The question pools for these tests are too small, which makes it extremely easy to get a high result on a re-take.

Comment: Imo, _"okay-ish"_ < _"Good enough to affiliate with SO"_

Comment: Yup. Take a look at my Developer Story for an example - the Python score is probably about accurate, but I'm not sure I'd call myself an expert in... uh... _any_ of the others.

Comment: It's a five minute test! What did you expect?! Sorry to burst the bubble, but 5 minutes are enough to make noodles, not to measure the knowledge someone has gained over the years.

Comment: @Nisarg Personally, it's not that I expected more of it - yeah, it's a five minute test, which is great for some things. It's that for the way it's been marketed - "use this as a canonical record of your skills on your CV and show it to employers!" - it's not up to the job.

Comment: Pluralsight states: [*"Our product is not intended to be used in hiring, firing, or promotion decisions and we make no warranties to our customers in regards to utilizing assessment results in the hiring process"*](https://help.pluralsight.com/help/should-i-use-skill-iq-ratings-for-hiring-firing-or-promotion-decisions). I would also argue that it *is* possible to give a reasonably accurate estimate of a developer's skill level in 5 minutes *if* you ask the right questions, although, judging by the many Meta posts, this isn't the case for most Pluralsight tests.

Comment: @vaultah: with such a broad disclaimer, what would have been the added value for Stack Overflow? I mean, I personally can broadly state exactly the same – and win myself a big fat SO contract.

Comment: I just took C# test and it was mostly about knowledge of some specific language details which are easy to google out. Not happy with the test (although was proficient in it).

Comment: I did several Android tests and found them quite appropriate. The only downside is that those test are Java-only, Kotlin is missing

Comment: I just took Python. I started learning Python **only *a month* ago** but I made it to 210+. This can be verified by watching [my Python posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+user%3A5958455). Ridiculous.

Comment: I have had more trouble understanding the questions themselves because of the high level of english. I did more wrong than good just because I did not fully understand the majority of the words used in the questions. There should be a translated version so everyone has an equal chance of getting a decent score.

Comment: @vaultah Sure, and my chocolate cookies are not meant for human consumption. Oh, you say you ate them anyway, because that's *obviously the only thing you'd ever do with them, and the entire purpose for which they were created*? Well, at least now you can't complain if they make you sick, because I warned you up-front that my product wasn't fit for its primary purpose and that obviously absolves me of all responsibility, right?

Comment: I really wonder whether tech companies really hire people without doing a tech interview themselves. These tests can help to identify potential candidates, but like IQ does not per se map perfectly on intelligence, Pluralsight IQ does not per se map on competences for a *specific* company. Some of the tests on PlularSight are about features that are very specific, some companies never use such features at all.

Comment: @mark send a complimentary box of your cookies to Pluralsight

Comment: SOs reputation based on tags is much more valuable than most of the tests IMHO.

Comment: I believe SO could have its own community-written, reviewed, and maintained database of questions instead of relying on Pluralsight.

Comment: The poor quality begins where they tell me it'll only take 5 minutes but they won't even let me start before agreeing to terms which I couldn't read in 5 minutes.

Comment: Pluralsight has a tough business model.  Every six months or so they lose all of their customers and they have to find a new set to keep the company going.  So they spend a lot of effort on banging their drum, everywhere there might be insufficiently trained future customers available.  If you can pass these tests then you're unlikely to be interesting to them and unlikely to need their services.

Comment: To get an idea [of the questions](https://github.com/tik9/pluralsight-skill-tests/blob/master/mysql.md)

Answer (score 52):

I had a very similar experience with the MySQL test: weighted more towards configuration options and server setups than towards querying (I don't think I encountered more than one or two questions about joins, which are arguably some of the most important operations on relational databases).

Some of the other tests I did (notably the HTML and JavaScript tests) were *better* weighted; however, every test I tried had, to a greater or lesser degree, the same problem. They all seem to be weighted more towards the theory and/or specifications of the language than towards the application. That seems fairly ineffective to me, since any developer worth their salary can Google the answer in less time than the question's time limit (or, in the case of JavaScript, just open the browser console and, y'know, *run the code they gave you*).

The other fairly major flaw I came across was that the tests are drawn from a very small pool of questions. Pluralsight offers you "one free retake" - once you've done a test once, you can do it again if you're not happy with the result and they'll keep your highest score. That's good in theory, but in practice the retakes were composed of 50% *or more* of the same questions - and since they give you the answers as you go along, you can just re-enter exactly what you were told five minutes ago and get a higher score. Which is a bit broken, to be honest.

Oh, and, of course, [some of its questions are just outright wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363251/pluralsight-iq-incorrect-questions-in-test?noredirect=1&lq=1).

A slightly more minor quibble: while they do appear to support a good subset of languages and frameworks, it's not a subset that represents the real usage of those languages. There's at least one major language missing - Ruby (and with it, Ruby on Rails) - and I wouldn't be surprised to see more.

TL;DR: Yes, I do think that the Pluralsight tests are poor quality. They're not all irrelevant, though there are certainly some (here's looking at you, MySQL), but the quality makes their relevancy mostly irrelevant (ha!).

Comment: There seems to be no test associated in any way with iOS either, which is a surprising gap, but maybe I should count myself lucky.

Comment: This is a serious, although perhaps not as acutely serious, issue in foreign language learning. It's better for most people to gain a basic level of fluency, even with grammatical errors, than for them to memorize tons of obscure verb conjugations (that they can regurgitate on a test) but find themselves unable to order lunch.

Comment: Tried the Java language one and it seemed more or less "balanced", although given the size of the test and breadth of the topic, still looks like a gadget. What I'm curious about is what happens once you've consumed your free retake: is their biz model solely based on users paying to get further retakes to improve artificial results (which could be thwarted by simply creating a new account, I suppose)?

Comment: They have a whole bunch of courses that they charge for, @Mena; this seems more like a promotional product.

Answer (score 28):

I helped Des put together [the initial rollout announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/add-an-assessment-to-your-developer-story), so here's my take on this...

### Pluralsight the company

They've been around for a good while now, and seem to be pretty well-regarded; I've seen recommendations from folks I trust (read: who aren't affiliated with them) for one course or another going back at least 4 years. They appear to be willing to find good people to put together the courses that they offer, and provide reasonable pricing for individuals.

Now... Whether that's your cup of tea is another matter; there are plenty of people who prefer to avoid coursework in favor of reading official documentation, blogs, answers on Stack Overflow, plain ol' *experimentation*... But for the folks who learn most effectively with a bit more structure, the company seems to be reasonably competent at what it does.

### Test quality

There are two parts to this: the value of trying to assign a number to a broad and deep area of knowledge, and the errors in the actual questions on the tests.

I wouldn't take the former too seriously; I mean, we do the same thing: you get a number for your reputation, numbers for your activity in each tag, even a number [when you run for moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election/252643#252643). They can be helpful in quickly estimating something complicated but as everyone here knows reputation is no substitute for *demonstrated expertise* in solving an actual problem...

...Which is perhaps the best reason to offer something like these tests: an awful lot of folks joining Stack Overflow for the first time seem to be a bit intimidated by all the numbers we throw at them, and implicitly undervalue their own experience and abilities. Taking a self-assessment - and seeing slightly-inflated results - has the potential to give new people the confidence to look past the numbers and focus on the real goal: helpful, accurate information.

Of course, that makes inaccurate answers on the tests themselves all the more problematic. This isn't all that *surprising*; I've observed this in pretty much every test I've ever taken, and spent many a fine hour arguing with test-takers over my results... But we should try to do better here. Des has been passing the feedback here on meta back to the folks at Pluralsight; hopefully we'll see some improvements as a result.

### Is this relevant to Stack Overflow?

I think so. In the broadest sense, it's a mechanism for self-evaluation that is now sorta built into the site; that's a useful thing to have when it works and a problem when it doesn't.

As several people have pointed out, Pluralsight's feedback mechanism is woefully inferior to ours: they don't have a meta or other mechanism for tracking reports. So if we want to see improvements, I think we need to be a bit more welcoming of feedback from people taking the test - at very least, stop telling [folks like Benjamin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363251/pluralsight-iq-incorrect-questions-in-test) that their detailed reports are off-topic. For as long as these tests are linked into Stack Overflow in some way, we should do our best to make them as accurate and useful as possible - and as with everything else here, that starts with open and honest discussion of specific problems.

Comment: I thought we used tag reputation as a measure of competency in a subject.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is, is there any reason to put it on the Developer Story? Would I do that just to feel good about myself? What would companies think about seeing yet another number on my CV? (And I find [this link vaulteh found](https://help.pluralsight.com/help/should-i-use-skill-iq-ratings-for-hiring-firing-or-promotion-decisions) particularly interesting.) If it's just for kicks and irrelevant to job stuff, then wouldn't the profile be a better place?

Comment: Strictly-speaking, it's a measure of *helpful participation* in that tag, @Bohemian; my top tag score is in JavaScript, which should definitely not be misconstrued as an indication of competence.

Comment: If you want to show it off, you certainly can @Andrew. AFAIK, it *can't* be added to your CV, so there's no employer exposure.

Comment: @AndrewMyers I wouldn't put it on a resume. It feels like those silly credentials and certifications people get, where nearly everyone that has and advertises them is _not_ someone you want to hire..

Comment: " I think we need to be a bit more welcoming of feedback from people taking the test - at very least, stop telling folks like Benjamin that their detailed reports are off-topic. " but that dude is a jerk and is just complaining because he's bad at JavaScript. In all seriousness though - since StackOverflow is the one in business with Pluralsight here - I think it would be great to have direct communication with Pluralsight (someone from PS responding, and taking feedback) - I think it would be very valuable info for them and would help them improve. Alternatively SO can also remove PS IQ.

Comment: "Taking a self-assessment - and seeing slightly-inflated results - has the potential to give new people the confidence to look past the numbers and focus on the real goal: helpful, accurate information." In other words, this is a study on controlling the Dunning-Kruger effect...

Comment: No, I'm still here @TylerH; Dunning-Kruger is alive and well. This is more about mitigating [impostor syndrome](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/brain-wise/201605/the-imposter-syndrome). Y'know, that thing that gets folks showing up here all sad panda every week 'cause they got a single downvote on something they wrote once and they're pretty sure we're all just about to tell 'em they've been found out and are gonna have to leave.

Comment: @Shog9 imposter syndrome is actually included in Dunning-Kruger, it's just the other end of the spectrum from what most people think. D-K is more accurately 'people who incorrectly estimate their own ability with something', most folks just use it for when people overestimate rather than those who underestimate.

Comment: I was being kinda flippant in my last reply @TylerH, but your response got me thinking - I didn't recall impostor syndrome being a part of what Dunning-Kruger tested. So I went back to the "unskilled and unaware" study [PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.64.2655&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and reviewed it; although they do describe a similar miscalculation by competent participants, they attribute it instead to the false consensus effect - they DO recognize their own competence but incorrectly assume others share it. Also: [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3432)

Comment: Pluralsight pay SE for this?

Comment: Beats me, @canon; AFAIK this is a test run to see if a more extensive partnership is worthwhile, but no idea what the terms are.

Answer (score 27):

I don't think the skill quizzes were designed to be used as an external display of competence. The way they are described on the site (for example, in the [welcome video](https://vimeo.com/234056588) and in [the FAQ](https://help.pluralsight.com/help/should-i-use-skill-iq-ratings-for-hiring-firing-or-promotion-decisions)) indicate that they are meant as a way to identify areas where personal development is needed.

Using them as an external display of skill seems contrary to their purpose. Even [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363290/2460971) refers to them as a way to self-evaluate.

That said, I have doubts about the quizzes' effectiveness as a form of self evaluation. I took three quizzes on subjects that I knew nothing about ([Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)), Nuke, and "Game Environment Modeling"). I managed to get a rating of *Proficient* in two of them and was in the 73rd percentile for "Game Environment Modeling". This was all on my first try without bothering to google any answers except during the Unity quiz.

In summary, I'm not sure why Stack Overflow thought Pluralsight's Skill IQ would be useful to display on the Developer Story. The quizzes are of low quality and using them as a public certification seems counter to their design.

Answer (score 10):

I have been using Pluralsight for a couple of years now, thus I know a thing or two about this "Skill IQ" thing they are marketing. "Skill IQ" is basically connected to their "Skill Path". They have a path like this for many of the skills -

[image: Pluralsight Paths]

The skill paths are a collection of few of their courses in the specified skills. The "Skill IQ" is a way to measure the growth of a user. Check the following picture for that.

[image: JS Path]

So, the content of the Skill IQ questions is from the "Skill Path" of that particular skill. It's from those video-courses. Thus if you have never watched those videos, it's slightly hard to exactly know the answers. Some of the content in those courses are very old. For example, there's one course in the JS path which was published in 2012. `ES5` was still new at that time and `ES2015` was known as `ES6` only. They keep adding fresh content, but it hardly makes it into the Skill Path (There are courses on Pluralsight about a particular skill which are not included in the Skill Path, for reasons I am not sure).

One of my colleagues tried the "Skill IQ" of their "Ethical Hacking (CEH prep)" path without any knowledge of CEH and got a proficient rating, just by clicking random guesses (He's a Python developer). So I am not so sure about the accuracy of the "Skill IQ".

However, I agree with the fact that they are just a number and trying to quantify an unquantifiable quality which is what Stack Overflow does too with the reputation mechanism. Overall, I am very happy to see the integrations and welcome the move. It allows more content for the developer story feature and it helps my favorite place on the internet get some money. Also, since the Skill IQ is here for more than a year now and companies are using that, I am assuming the accuracy check should be the responsibility of the companies that are looking for the particular skills in a candidate.

Comment: I'm not sure its even possible to score below "proficient" unless you're actively *trying* to score low. As [Suma said in an answer on another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363268/1663383), he took tests about things he knew literally nothing about and scored a 41% (that's a proficient!) *at the lowest.* I assume that was without a retake. ArtOfCode (comment on this question) has a similar remark.

Comment: Can `you` dial `down` the `formatting` a `little`? It's meant for bits and pieces of code.

Comment: @Nisarg Pekka did that already

Comment: @Draco18s I did score novice in docker skill and I was not even trying to score low. I was just not proficient in that.

Comment: Based on your answer 'Skill IQ' is only useful (if at all) for people who took the courses, it was completely misused when it was marketed to all SO users as a measurement of expertise. I'm curious why are you happy and welcome a move that makes SO look extremely amateurish and unprofessional?

Comment: @Oleg It doesn't make SO look amateurish and unprofessional if they are using a third party integration which is relied upon by the industry. Pluralsight IQ is one parameter over which a company may choose to select a candidate, but if they are giving it a lot of priority, it's the issue with the company. This is similar to how giving SO reputation a lot of priority instead of the actual work experience is amateurish.

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**

Selfquote:

> Sure - and it might be the best decision to remove the connection, as
>   they still have a long way to go

## Preamble

As long as Pluralsight is connected to Stack Overflow we <del>have to</del> should make the best of it. So we need to help Pluralsight to improve the quality of the questions and try to give constructive feedback. The Stack Overflow community clearly is an expert for Q&A, so Pluralsight can benefit from the experience this community has gathered over the years.

## Problem - Question Pool Size

I just have taken the C# and the [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)) measurements. Both results were okay the first time. I can't say the questions were of poor quality - but what made my second attempts way better was, that (at least in the Unity retake) I had about 50% of the exact same questions I had before. That clearly helped me to get a better result in the retake, as I instantly started the retake whilst having the answers still in memory. On the other side, I didn't have that many repetitions when doing the retake in C#.

## Solution

The pool of the questions simply needs to be bigger. If there are not that many repetitive questions the skill measurement would at least have a little more relevance.

## Problem - Covered Skills

I just stepped over another thing - where are the Swift/Objective-C and iOS stuff? And where is the [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) or [Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin) stuff? (I bet most web developers could state an endless list of frameworks and languages that are missing.)

[image: Screenshot from available measurements]

## Problem - Cheating

So, if I'm not happy with my results - I just create a new e-mail on my mail server and try it again? Repeat until skill level of 300 was reached. What's the point of that rating?

> I guess I need to try if I can simply create another Pluralsight account
>   and also link that to the same SO account.

If someone has already tried that - please link me the post. Otherwise, I'll try if that is possible tomorrow and edit the post.

## Conclusion for the current state

At the current state, these measurements are kind of irrelevant. As there seem to be [**some incorrect questions/answers**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363251/pluralsight-iq-incorrect-questions-in-test) and the **pool of questions** per skill feels to be too small. Also the some (in my opinion) important **technologies** are missing. And on top of that, there is always the option to **simply google the answers**.

### The positive side of the Pluralsight integration

I have never heard of Pluralsight before. And I bet I would never have if it wouldn't be connected to Stack Overflow. So as I now know that this platform exists, I took measurements and learned, that I still have *a lot* to learn. And that is the most important part for me. I haven't reached any level near maximum and I want to improve myself - not to get a better number on Pluralsight, but to increase my knowledge for the sake of writing better code.

This skill level might not be relevant for hiring or similar things, but at least people can get a hint how much they still have to learn in a specific topic - at least if the question offers the correct answers :P

Comment: How about we slap a question ban on them for asking too many bad questions? :)

Comment: That would be okay for me, but we could also use the immense knowledge of the SO community and help them fix the bad questions. Maybe we should link them to [ask] in order to ask better questions.

Comment: _"As Pluralsight is now connected to SO we have to make the best of it."_ Or we can just remove the connection again.

Comment: Sure - and it might be the best decision to remove the connection, as they still have a long way to go

Comment: SO shouldn't be used as an incubator and life support for a poorly implemented commercial venture. The company is 14 years old. If it is not getting things right now, quality is obviously not a corporate value.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to Stack Overflow this month and I discovered PluralSight by creating my profile.

So I passed some tests and indeed we can ask the question of the validity and relevance of the results.

I think there is a misunderstanding about the nature of these Skills IQ tests.

Indeed, these tests that last a few minutes with 20 questions are not really tests of aptitude and knowledge in a technology strictly speaking.

These are **intelligence tests** in the area of the test theme, not **ability tests**.

For example, for C#, C++ and Java tests, it is not a matter of evaluating the technical level and the ability to be ready to program as a novice or an advanced in the language, it is in fact to measure the conceptual level and the ability to embrace the technology.

An IQ test will not measure knowledge itself in a field, it will measure the faculty of apprehending the concepts of this field. While a minimum of knowledge is required, the test will essentially measure the mind's ability to adapt its concepts and not to use in the real world the objects themselves.

For example, I never wrote Java code. I have already worked on a Delphi program generating Java code from a physical model of data, but I have never made a software in Java, no line of code. I did, however, get a higher score than the C# IQ test with which I'm working for many many years and my first reaction was to be confused.

So I think that PluralSight's Skills IQ do not measure the technical level but the level of the concepts, and that these tests are an indication not of the ability to use a particular technology in terms of operational level, but of the ability to immerse yourself in this technology thanks to the abstract knowledge of this field and of neighboring domains you already know.

So it is not a question here of a practice in the use of artifacts of a technology but of mastering the concepts of these artifacts.

*So these Skills IQ can indicate whether you are in front of an ignorant in computer science and in a particular field of a discipline (0-50), a beginner (50-100), an initiated (100-150), an advanced (150-200), an expert (200-250) or a master (>250), not in a technology itself but in its abstraction.*

[Intelligence Quotient @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient)