# Pluralsight SkillIQ Improved?

Tags: discussion, pluralsight-iq

Back in 2018 the community considered whether Pluralsight's Skill IQ tests were of relevance or value to Stack Overflow ([Pluralsight IQ credibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363279/pluralsight-iq-credibility-and-quality-relevance-of-their-tests)). Part of the discussion noted that an ongoing dialog between Stack Overflow and Pluralsight had the potential to improve the quality of the tests.

In the opinion of the community, has there been any significant improvement over the last 3+ years?

Comment: I recently re-took a test for vuejs and can say that the quality of their questions has increased a lot.

Comment: I'm also curious if we will even continue doing anything with Pluralsight once the developer story is removed next year and there will no longer be any place to show it off.

Comment: @animuson lol, dev story is getting axed? Did SO finally get a clue or will it be replaced by something worse?

Comment: @animuson The developer story is going away? I missed that announcement

Comment: @DavidG not announced yet, but already hinted on few comments: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409169/how-do-small-companies-post-jobs-on-stack-overflow/410974#comment862604_410974), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411216/duplicated-master-data-of-companies-universities-etc-in-developer-story/411253#comment865365_411253)

Comment: @l4mpi (you might want to read the comment above regarding "dev story is getting axed")

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks for the links, that reads like it will just be dropped without replacement. Which is great IMO as it felt like a bad attempt at becoming the next linkedin; cleaning up the wannabe social-network features seems like a step in the right direction.

Comment: I never see a topic talking about Pluralsight SkillQ, and never see it on SE network. Is that a SE feature?

Comment: Does anybody other than beginners miss a deadline due to not knowing C# trivia well enough? I haven't since I was a beginner and didn't know how to handle things like native resources and reliable file I/O. Usually what results in success or failure is product design, not coding (good communication with customers, good system design, etc.). I ended up wearing the "product design" hat 80%+ of the time because I knew that the 20% coding part was not that important, relatively speaking.

Answer (score 34):

I opened the initial complaint last time [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363251/incorrect-questions-in-pluralsight-iq-test). So I was eager to check.

This time I took the "IQ" test in Node.js fundamentals (I am a Node.js core team member and maintainer). **The impression was less than great.**

#### The good news

None of the answers and questions were incorrect and I was able to get all of them right by answering them straight up.

#### The bad news

This test does not measure my expertise in Node.js at all! It does not cover any of the fundamentals of Node.js programming. It instead asks trivia questions about the APIs of unrelated third-party libraries (MongoDB Node.js driver, Sinon.JS), trivia about rarely used APIs you'd just look up if you need to use (I would and I code-reviewed a lot of them myself) etc.

- Imagine doing a Python test and getting all NumPy questions (or if you use NumPy - Django specific questions - or have all the questions be MyPy edge cases).
- Or doing a C++ test and getting all questions about the SQLite C++ API.
- Or doing a Java test and getting all Android API questions (if you do Android - imagine getting Spring questions or Hadoop questions etc).

---

Questions were:

- Something about specific MongoDB syntax (it's a Node.js course not a MongoDB one).
- A question about `require` caching dependencies (which I guess is OK but is such "trivia" and not core Node.js knowledge - even if we ignore people should really be using ESM).
- Another MongoDB specific question (using old callback syntax).
- A question about `npm audit` (with an incorrect answer IMO, but I am not speaking for my employer here).
- Another MongoDB question (trivia, not concept).
- Another MongoDB question (trivia, not concept).
- An OAuth URL structure question.
- An NPM internals question about local package installation.
- A Sinon.JS API trivia question (api, not concept). Fun fact - I am also a Sinon.JS maintainer and I googled it to be sure.
- A question about a specific Node.js crypto API most people would not use.
- Another crypto API question (though this time with an obvious answer).
- A question about HTTP Authorization headers.
- Another crypto API question.
- A question asking you to list the various NPM hooks.
- An actual honest-to-god Node.js question! The first one - about file directory reading.
- Another MongoDB question.
- A really long crypto trivia question.

I got all of them correct but none of them actually measure my Node.js proficiency.

Comment: As a side note I just starting doing the JavaScript test next and it's a lot more decent so far.

Comment: As another side note: The PowerShell quiz was very basic at first but quickly delved into remote management protocol differences between Windows and Linux hosts. Basically the nuts and bolts underlying the cross platform compatibility. Somewhat esoteric but all 100% core to the tool.

Comment: So TL;DR it might no longer be the dumpster fire it was a few years ago, but is still absolutely unfit for evaluating the actual skill level? Sounds about right, I mean what else can you expect from a short web based quiz about a topic... and that's before we start talking about all of the meta problems with such a test (e.g. you can have your friend or google answer questions for you).

Comment: Not sure if you noticed this or not. But the SkillIQ questions are from the courses' questions banks associated with the topic's learning path on Pluralsight. So for Nodejs path [ https://imgur.com/a/PXQerPf ] the content of the courses is already about stuff like MongoDB, Sinon, OAuth, and others and how to use them in node. That's why you got the questions that you got, in case you're wondering.

Comment: The screenshot above is for Working with Nodejs path. apparently, there's another older path called just "Nodejs" [ https://imgur.com/a/eNuckUn ] that has crypto content among others which is why you also found crypto questions

Comment: I took the PHP test recently and of the 18 questions, I gave negative feedback on 16 of them. 7 for "Not Relevant", 4 for "Technical Accuracy", and 5 for "Question Clarity." One of the questions had to do with knowing detail about some obscure 3rd party library I had never heard of. When I looked it up, it had been deprecated 8 years ago. A number of questions had opinion-based answers. Some had flat-out invalid source examples containing syntax errors. Some used the wrong words in very important places, like class instead of method. It was pretty terrible.

Answer (score 21):

I feel like I should post another answer since I just did the JavaScript quiz and **the JavaScript quiz was pretty decent!** It was [nothing like the Node.js quiz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412110/1348195).

There was only one incorrect question/answer and 1/2 questions that were absolute trivia but the test overall covered reasonable topics (closures/prototypes/primitive-object-duality etc) as well as *some* asynchronisity concepts (like promise API).

I would have designed the test differently personally but I think it's a fair assessment of someone's JavaScript knowledge. This surprised me enough to post a separate answer since I feel that good feedback is also important.