# Unable to cancel adding an Assessment on Developer Story

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

I was exploring the options one has available to include on one's Developer Story, and happened to notice that I *can't cancel an attempt to [add an Assessment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/add-an-assessment-to-your-developer-story) item*:

[image]

Whenever I click that button it simply just doesn't do anything and the screen remains the same.

Further exploring I noticed that other options Cancel button works correctly. Inspecting them closer, I can see that **the Assessment Option's button redirects to a different link than the other options**:

- Other buttons: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/3908170#item-add
- Assessment button: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/3908170#assessment-0

Perhaps that has something to do with this behavior. **Is there something I am missing or doing wrong here? Does anybody else experience this as well?**

Comment: Checking it out :) I was able to reproduce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting it! This should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I managed to overcome the situation by refreshing or manually erasing the # on the link. Will be checking the change and comment here when it's live.

Comment: Indeed, now works perfectly. Thank you :)